# Cannot get eslint to throw warning for no jsDoc on Ember classes, props, actions

Tags: javascript, ember.js, eslint, jsdoc

I am setting up eslint in my ember project. I want to enforce that all functions, classes, actions, and properties are documented with jsDoc.

The problem that I am facing is that I cannot seem to get the enforcement to work on actions, component declarations, or object properties.

I originally tried "require-jsdoc" but also noted that this rule is deprecated. I then installed eslint-plugin-jsdoc with the following config:

```
rules: [
  ...
  'jsdoc/check-examples': 0,
  'jsdoc/check-param-names': 1,
  'jsdoc/check-tag-names': 1,
  'jsdoc/check-types': 1,
  'jsdoc/newline-after-description': 1,
  'jsdoc/no-undefined-types': 1,
  'jsdoc/require-description': 1,
  'jsdoc/require-description-complete-sentence': 1,
  'jsdoc/require-example': 1,
  'jsdoc/require-hyphen-before-param-description': 1,
  'jsdoc/require-param': 1,
  'jsdoc/require-param-description': 1,
  'jsdoc/require-param-name': 1,
  'jsdoc/require-param-type': 1,
  'jsdoc/require-returns': 1,
  'jsdoc/require-returns-check': 1,
  'jsdoc/require-returns-description': 1,
  'jsdoc/require-returns-type': 1,
]
```

And still no luck. Any idea how to get the following working?

```js
// throw eslint warning if not documented
export default Component.extend({
  someProp: false, // throw eslint warning if not documented
  actions: {
    someAction() {} // throw eslint warning if not documented
  }
});
```

All other natural function definitions are working as expected, just attempting to get these cases working. Thanks!

Comment: `rules` element should be a json object instead of array. In your code it seems that you've defined it between `[ ]` instead of `{ }`. If so, it might be related to it.

Comment: That was my bad in writing the question, it is an object. I solved this, turns out I needed to open a new terminal session to get my VIM ALE to reflect the changes (thats a whole other problem) :) Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Do you have `"plugins": ["jsdoc"]` in your config?

Answer (score 4):

As `require-jsdoc` is deprecated, the correct way of checking for the presence of JSDoc comments on class declarations and functions is installing [`eslint-plugin-jsdoc`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jsdoc) plugin and using `jsdoc/require-jsdoc` rule.

Once you have:

```js
rules: [
  ...
  'jsdoc/require-jsdoc': 1,
  ...
]
```

ESLint will start warning about missing comments. If you *do* include some comment, then all other rules like `jsdoc/require-description` or `jsdoc/require-param` will be enforced.

Note that `jsdoc/require-jsdoc` rule needs some configuration if you want it to apply to more than just function declarations. For example:

```js
rules: [
  ...
  'jsdoc/require-jsdoc': [1, {'require': {
    FunctionExpression: true,
    ClassDeclaration: true
  }}],
  ...
]
```